# A custom angular two-state checkbox component issue

Tags: angular, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox component to replace an old-old NG Prime version that had been being used but wanted to make it leaner/cleaner with some added aria points and utilizing more of the checkbox attributes directly. The problem I'm running into though (I'm guessing) is with updating the value accessor / ngmodel and could use some guidance on what I'm apparently missing...

I thought what I had was simplistic enough but apparently not. The idea is that `@Input() binary` is set to `true` by default expecting `ngModel` to have a boolean to use but I don't get the value from `ngModel` when it's initialized. I need `ngModel` to communicate that to the component though when it's used standalone as like `<app-checkbox [ngModel]="blah"></app-checkbox>` but also have `value_accessor` working as expected if it's used in say a reactive angular form etc.

I also get a "NG0303: Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'app-checkbox'" in my instance, but it's not on the stackblitz which I don't understand.

[A Stackblitz showing the implementation / problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kmbgm4)

(the example is angular 12, I use 13, but it's fine for the example)

And for quick code reference;

.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  forwardRef,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { ObjectUtils } from '../objectUtils';

export const CHECKBOX_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxComponent),
  multi: true,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.css'],
  providers: [CHECKBOX_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() value: any;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() ariaLabelledBy: string;
  @Input() ariaLabel: string;
  @Input() tabindex: number;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() labelStyleClass: string;
  @Input() formControl: FormControl;
  @Input() required: boolean = false;
  @Input() isValid: boolean = true;
  @Input() invalidMessage: string;

  // This is set true by default now since every instance at the time this replacement component was made requires it for a boolean value bound to ngModel
  // If in the future we start using angular reactive forms more it can be toggled at the instance.
  @Input() binary: boolean = true;

  @ViewChild('cb') inputViewChild: ElementRef;

  @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  isChecked: boolean = false;

  focused: boolean = false;
  model: any;
  onModelChange: Function = () => {};
  onModelTouched: Function = () => {};

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.id
      ? this.id
      : `tcl-cb-${Math.random()
          .toString()
          .substr(2, length ? length : 6)}`;
  }

  updateModel(event) {
    let newModelValue;

    if (!this.binary) {
      if (this.isChecked) {
        newModelValue = this.model.filter(
          (val) => !ObjectUtils.equals(val, this.value)
        );
      } else {
        newModelValue = this.model ? [...this.model, this.value] : [this.value];
      }

      this.onModelChange(newModelValue);
      this.model = newModelValue;

      if (this.formControl) {
        this.formControl.setValue(newModelValue);
      }
    } else {
      newModelValue = this.isChecked;
      this.model = newModelValue;
      this.onModelChange(newModelValue);
    }

    this.onChange.emit({ checked: newModelValue, originalEvent: event });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.isChecked = event.srcElement.checked;
    if (!this.disabled) {
      this.updateModel(event);
    }
  }

  onFocus() {
    this.focused = true;
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.focused = false;
    this.onModelTouched();
  }

  focus() {
    this.inputViewChild.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  writeValue(model: any): void {
    this.model = model;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
    this.onModelChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
    this.onModelTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(val: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = val;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

html

```
<div role="group" class="app-checkbox">
  <input
    #cb
    type="checkbox"
    [attr.id]="id"
    [attr.name]="name"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [value]="value"
    [checked]="isChecked"
    [attr.tabindex]="tabindex"
    [attr.required]="required"
    [attr.aria-labelledby]="ariaLabelledBy"
    [attr.aria-label]="ariaLabel"
    [attr.aria-checked]="isChecked"
    (focus)="onFocus()"
    (blur)="onBlur()"
    (change)="handleChange($event)"
  />
  <label *ngIf="label" [attr.for]="id" [class]="labelStyleClass">
    {{ label }} <sup *ngIf="required">*</sup>
  </label>
  <div *ngIf="!isValid" class="tcl-checkbox-invalid-msg">
    {{ invalidMessage }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Any insight is appreciated especially if there's anything additional being forgotten!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need ngModel to communicate that to the component though when it's used standalone as like <app-checkbox [ngModel]="blah"> but also have value_accessor working as expected if it's used in say a reactive angular form etc.

In your case `ngModel` does communicate the value to your custom checkbox component, but you are not using the received value within your template to bind it to the `input`.

When using

```html
<app-checkbox [ngModel]="isChecked"></app-checkbox>
```

or

```html
<!-- If isChecked is FormControl name -->
<app-checkbox formControlName="isChecked"></app-checkbox>
```

the `writeValue` method is called passing it the form control value.

Within `writeValue` method you are setting `this.model`, but in your template you are using `isChecked` to bind to input `checked` property, and hence the checkbox isn't checked. You need to bind the value received from forms module to the correct property within your custom component, in your case it would be:

```ts
// within writeValue method
this.isChecked = model;
```

> I also get a "NG0303: Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'app-checkbox'" in my instance, but it's not on the stackblitz which I don't understand.

If you are getting the above error when doing something as below, then that's a valid error which you will also get in your stackblitz example. The reason being, `CheckboxComponent` doesn't have any input property named `checked`.

```html
<app-checkbox [checked]="isChecked"></app-checkbox>
```

Comment: I ended up going a different direction but this was closest thanks

Answer (score 0):

this would work and also you can simplify your `updateModel` function. logic is a bit complicated.

`model` was change after component loads, you just need to catch it and set the value of the isChecked to what is the value provided outside the component.

```
  @Input()
  get model() {
    return this.isChecked;
  }
  set model(v: any) {
    this.isChecked = v;
  }
```